# Is it possible Schedule Screen saver at specific times?

Tags: windows, screensaver

I am using windows 10 pro system and i would like to run screensaver at specific time to make a notice of Shut down Computer before leaving. Is it possible? even with a third party software or commands?

Comment: do you mean specific time as in, "Start screen saver at 8pm", or specific time as in "After being logged in for 5 hours"?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you already know about the Windows Task Scheduler - you should download http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html and create a batch file with the "start default screen saver" command, and schedule that batch file with the Task Scheduler

Comment: sorry i'm unable to follow this, would you please summarize the answer

Comment: So to clarify, you want to start your screensaver at a specific time (lets say 5pm every day), or what?

Comment: yeap exactly at 5:30 PM

Comment: then you can easily write a batch script for that with the tool i linked and tell the windows task scheduler to execute that script every day at 5:30 PM - if you have questions to that you should open a new question for the Task Scheduler or for the nircmd tool